# How do I treat a Gaussian beam through an axicon?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

An [axicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axicon) is a lens with a conical surface.

Where would I start if I want to do what it does to an input Gaussian beam?

Comment: You can always use Fermat's principle to get the actual path.

Comment: Does also work for Gaussian optics?

Comment: It is THE universal principle, so yes, it works everywhere. In fact, it is a good method to get the usual formulas. You can always use the paraxial reults though.

Comment: For general uses of an axicon, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axicon. For Gaussian beams specifically, try this. http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09500349908231354?journalCode=tmop20.    Short answer - it can produce a donut shaped beam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axicons are used to produce Bessel beams. Strictly speaking the result is not actually a Bessel beam, but it is a close approximation that is often good enough for some experimental purposes.

Analytically, one may try to model it by a phase-only transmission function
$$ t_{\rm axicon} = \exp( -i k r) , $$
where $r$ is the radial coordinate and $k$ is a parameter that determines the cone angle of the axicon (i.e., the amount of refraction that it produced).